# Fix: JS recursive function to get the nested (multilevel) child objects as array of objects

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to get the output as:

```
options: [{
  id: 'parent1',
  label: 'parent1',
  children: [{
    id: 'child1',
    label: 'child1',
    children: [{
      id: 'lastChild1',
      label: 'lastChild1',
    }]
  }, { 
    id: 'child2',
    label: 'child2',
    children: [{
      id: 'lastChild2',
      label: 'lastChild2',
    }]
  }]
}]
```

However, the output from `getOptions()` is in the format where the children property array of `parent1` object contain only the second child in the above format, first child is kind of overwritten or not visited by the `for..in` loop in the `recurseList()`.

Can anyone fix the code to output the first child `child1` along with `child2` as well, basically any level of nesting.

```
var myObj = {
  parent1: {
    child1: {
      lastChild1: { test: 'cool'}
    },
    child2: {
      lastChild2: { test: 'cool'}
    }
  },
  parent2: {
    child2_1: {
      lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool'}
    },
    child2_2: {
      lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool'}
    }
  }
}

var result = getOptions(myObj)
console.log('result', result)

function getOptions(obj) {
  var options = []
  for (key in obj) {
    var data = recurseList(obj[key])
    options.push(data)
  }
  return options
}

function recurseList(obj) {
  let data= {}
  let option= []
  for (key in obj) {
    data.id = key
    data.label = key
    data.children = []

    if(obj[key] instanceof Object) {
      var val = recurseList(obj[key])
      data.children.push(val)
    }
  }
  return data
}
```

Actually, I want data from my firebase real-time-database as show in the image below:

[image: firebase real-time-database snapshot]

to be in the format for this vuejs plugin: https://vue-treeselect.js.org

Thanks

Comment: If you want to recurse to any level, how do you distinguish between, say `parent2` or `lastchild1` and `test`?  Is it only because the value of the former ones are objects and the latter is a string?  Or is there something else going on with property names or some such?

Comment: @ScottSauyet So actually, I do not want the object properties in the output at all, I only want the nodes as in the options data structure of this VueJS plugin https://vue-treeselect.js.org. Thanks

Comment: Ok, asked another way, why does `{id: 'lastChild1', label: 'lastChild1'}` in your sample output above not include `children: {id: 'test', label: 'test'}`?  What distinguishes the node `test` from any of its ancestor nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const myObj = {
        parent1: {
            child1: {
                lastChild1: { test: 'cool'}
            },
            child2: {
                lastChild2: { test: 'cool'}
            }
        },
        parent2: {
            child2_1: {
                lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool'}
            },
            child2_2: {
                lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool'}
            }
        }
    }


function getOptions(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        acc.push({
          id: cur,
          label: cur,
          children: recurseList(obj[cur])
        })
        return acc;
    }, [])
}
  
function recurseList(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if(obj[cur] instanceof Object) {
            let data = {
                id: cur,
                label:cur
            }      
            const children = recurseList(obj[cur]);
            If(children.length) {
                  data.children = children
            }
            acc.push(data)
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
}

var result = getOptions(myObj)
console.log('result', result)
```

The problem is that you always use empty `children` array in a loop. And also you are not using your very first `key parent1` to push to your result array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your output is not the desired output I want, Pls refer to the top of my question. The output I want is 

`children: [{
    id: 'child1',
    label: 'child1',
    children: [{
        id: 'lastChild1',
        label: 'lastChild1',
      }]
    }, 
    { id: 'child2',
    label: 'child2',
    children: [{
        id: 'lastChild2',
        label: 'lastChild2',
      }]
   }]`

Comment: Check now please if that is what you expect.

Comment: Hi Daniyal, sorry no but that again is incorrect. Actually I am trying to get the options array as this VueJS plugin requires for data from my firebase real-time-database source. https://vue-treeselect.js.org. [[Also edited my question with this additional info]]

Comment: Isn't the output the same?)

Comment: No, The output does not contain `child1`. Moreover it's descendant i.e. `last_child1` gets clubbed with `last_child1` under `child2`. Output should be

Parent1
   |_ child1
   |       |_last_child1

   |_ child1
          |_last_child1

Comment: The desired data structure should as shown in this [screenshot output image](https://monosnap.com/file/S5AT5axW2zfbNrhdJkxVFsJMGn8N8i)

Comment: Hi, That's gr8 but there is one problem, the first children (of parent) needs to be an array containing child objects. so like this `"label": "parent1",    "children": [{ }]`. This screenshot shows where the [problem is here](https://monosnap.com/file/EKjTCY1NS9Uy7oniNA2DxH71s7bU0b)

Comment: @appu I fixed that. That was my mistake, sorry. I think now the final version is giving the desired output.

Comment: That's gr8 Daniyal. Can u also not have the properties of the last object node in the output i.e `"children": [
            {
              "id": "test",
              "label": "test"
            }
          ]` is not required. Thanks

Comment: Daniyal [Pls see this](https://monosnap.com/file/9ugdcEAGUEQwkOyElu6FUxdLGWb8FI), this is what  I don't want.

Comment: Daniyal this is a gr8, wonderful, Thanks for your time and effort. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: @appu No need in thanks )) Just accept the answer if it helped you out.

Comment: While the overall solution is fine, this line is fairly confusing: `children.length ? data.children = children : true;`  I'm all for avoiding `if` statements -- but using a conditional expression for side-effects is faintly horrifying.

Comment: @ScottSauyet do you mean that it would be better to use `if` instead of ternary operator?

Comment: Well, I'm all for avoiding statements entirely, and working with expressions as much as possible, and that means ternary/conditionals when possible.  But using an assignment statement as one segment of the ternary, and even more than that, writing a ternary where you ignore its result, and put a dummy statement (here `: true`) in order to skip some syntax just makes things confusing.

Comment: @ScottSauyet agree. Replaced with the `if`

Answer (score 2):

**variable depth**

Here's an adaptation to Scott's (wonderful) answer that allows you to convert your nested structure to a user-controlled depth; `convertUntil` -

1. If the input, `o`, is not an object, (base case) there is nothing to convert, return the input
2. Otherwise, (inductive) the input *is* an object. If, the object passes the user-supplied `test`, stop nesting and return `children: {}`
3. Otherwise, (inductive) the input *is* an object but it does *not* pass the user-supplied `test`. Map over the input object and create a level of our output structure. Recur `convertUntil` on each object value.

Numbered comments above correspond to the code below -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const convertUntil = (test = identity, o = {}) =>
  Object (o) !== o  // 1
    ? o
: test (o)          // 2
    ? {}
: Object
    .entries (o)    // 3
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          ({ id: k, label: k, children: convertUntil (test, v) })
      )

const myObj =
  { parent1:
      { child1: { lastChild1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2: { lastChild2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  , parent2:
      { child2_1: { lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2_2: { lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  }

console .log (convertUntil (x => x.test === "cool", myObj))
```

---

While I prefer this more consistent data structure, I can understand if you don't like the empty `children: {}` created above. With a slight modification, we can remove empty `children` properties -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const convertUntil = (test = identity, o = {}) =>
  Object (o) !== o
    ? o
: Object
    .entries (o)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          test (v) // <-- test here
            ? { id: k, label: k } // <-- no children
            : { id: k, label: k, children: convertUntil (test, v) }
      )

const myObj =
  { parent1:
      { child1: { lastChild1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2: { lastChild2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  , parent2:
      { child2_1: { lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2_2: { lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  }

console .log (convertUntil (x => x.test === "cool", myObj))
```

But watch out for -

```js
console .log (convertUntil (x => x.test === "cool", { test: "cool" }))
// [ { id: "test", label: "test", children: "cool" } ]
```

---

**fixed depth**

Another option would be to convert the nested structure to a specified `depth` -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const convert = (o = {}, depth = 0) =>
  Object (o) !== o
    ? o
: Object
    .entries (o)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          depth === 0 // <-- depth test
            ? { id: k, label: k } // <-- no children
            : { id: k, label: k, children: convert (v, depth - 1) } // <-- depth minus one
      )

const myObj =
  { parent1:
      { child1: { lastChild1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2: { lastChild2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  , parent2:
      { child2_1: { lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2_2: { lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  }

// show various depths
for (const d of [ 0, 1, 2 ])
  console .log (`depth: ${d}`, convert (myObj, d))
```

---

**combined technique**

Per Scott's comment, the techniques can be combined into a single solution. This allows the user to continue conversion based on the object's properties *or* a specified `depth` level -

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const convertUntil = (test = identity, o = {}, depth = 0) =>
  Object (o) !== o
    ? o
: Object
    .entries (o)
    .map
      ( ([ k, v ]) =>
          test (v, depth) // <-- include depth in test
            ? { id: k, label: k }
            : { id: k, label: k, children: convertUntil (test, v, depth + 1) } // <-- depth plus one
      )

const myObj =
  { parent1:
      { child1: { lastChild1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2: { lastChild2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  , parent2:
      { child2_1: { lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool' } }
      , child2_2: { lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool' } }
      }
  }

console .log (convertUntil ((_, depth) => depth === 2, myObj))
```

Comment: Very nice.  Obviously if my assumption about the decision is correct, then one could just pass the converse of my `hasObjectProperties` to this.

Comment: An interesting possibly extension would be to maintain a `depth` value and add that as an argument to `test`, allowing the user to cut off at an explicit level of nesting.

Comment: I was originally thinking of using an integer `depth` as well but opted for the higher-order function. Adding `depth` as a parameter to the user's `test` is a convenient enhancement. Thanks for the comment ^^

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to distinguish the `test` node from the other nodes, then I think this is straightforward:

```js
const convert = (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => ({
    id: k, 
    label: k,
    ...(typeof v == 'object' ? {children: convert (v)} : {})
  }))

const myObj = {
  parent1: {child1: {lastChild1: { test: 'cool'}}, child2: {lastChild2: { test: 'cool'}}},
  parent2: {child2_1: {lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool'}}, child2_2: {lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool'}}}
}

console .log (
  convert (myObj)
)
```

I'm guessing that distinguishing that deepest node would make this significantly more complex.

### Update

Ok, so it's not that much more complex, if the condition is that the object has no properties which are themselves objects.  (This is still not clear, and the requested output sample and the image posted as a comment on another answer seem to disagree.  But that would be my best guess.)  We can do this with either an inline test:

```
const convert = (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => ({
    id: k, 
    label: k,
    ...((typeof v == 'object' && Object .values (v) .some (o => typeof o == 'object'))
         ? {children: convert (v)} 
         : {}
       )
  }))
```

or with a helper function:

```
const hasObjectProperties = (obj) =>
  Object .values (obj) .some (o => typeof o == 'object')

const convert = (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => ({
    id: k, 
    label: k,
    ...((typeof v == 'object' && hasObjectProperties(v))
         ? {children: convert (v)} 
         : {}
       )
  }))
```

Using the latter, the code becomes:

```js
const hasObjectProperties = (obj) =>
  Object .values (obj) .some (o => typeof o == 'object')

const convert = (obj) =>
  Object .entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => ({
    id: k, 
    label: k,
    ...((typeof v == 'object' && hasObjectProperties(v))
         ? {children: convert (v)} 
         : {}
       )
  }))

const myObj = {
  parent1: {child1: {lastChild1: { test: 'cool'}}, child2: {lastChild2: { test: 'cool'}}},
  parent2: {child2_1: {lastChild2_1: { test: 'cool'}}, child2_2: {lastChild2_2: { test: 'cool'}}}
}

console .log (
  convert (myObj)
)
```

Comment: This is a very nice soln, I like it a lot. Cool & terse however the last node's properties/data shouldn't be in the output. Thanks.

Comment: Updated to fix that.  It wasn't as complex as I expected.  Still not sure if my assumption about when to skip a node was correct (that is if it doesn't have any child properties which are objects.)